# Intermittent connection from Nginx in Minikube

Tags: nginx, minikube

I'm experiencing this error from Nginx, running in minikube:

```
    2024/03/21 07:07:05 [error] 22#22: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.244.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.101.14.185:80/", host: "192.168.49.2:30590"
    10.244.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2024:07:07:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 497 "-" "curl/8.3.0" "-"
    10.244.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2024:07:07:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 307 0 "-" "curl/8.3.0" "-"
    10.244.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2024:07:07:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 307 0 "-" "curl/8.3.0" "-"
    2024/03/21 07:07:08 [error] 22#22: *15 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.244.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.101.14.185:80/", host: "192.168.49.2:30590"
    10.244.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2024:07:07:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 497 "-" "curl/8.3.0" "-"
```

My minikube setup

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/abc-deployment-7bf886b77d-fqnn4     1/1     Running   0          15m
pod/abc-deployment-7bf886b77d-xg7n4     1/1     Running   0          15m
pod/frontend-9b5d57d49-2gmlc            1/1     Running   0          6m33s
pod/mongodb-deployment-0                1/1     Running   0          15m

NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/abc-service        ClusterIP      10.101.14.185   <none>        80/TCP         15m
service/frontend           LoadBalancer   10.99.135.28    <pending>     80:30590/TCP   15m
service/kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        18m
service/mongodb-service2   ClusterIP      10.96.89.248    <none>        27018/TCP      15m

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/abc-deployment     2/2     2            2           15m
deployment.apps/frontend           1/1     1            1           6m33s

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/abc-deployment-7bf886b77d     2         2         2       15m
replicaset.apps/frontend-9b5d57d49            1         1         1       6m33s

NAME                                  READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/mongodb-deployment   1/1     15m
```

My nginx setup: default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://abc-service;
      proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            #        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            #        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

The service url:

```
| NAMESPACE |   NAME   | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|----------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | frontend |          80 | http://192.168.49.2:30590 |
|-----------|----------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Opening service default/frontend in default browser...
  http://192.168.49.2:30590
```

The pod host config:

```
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.244.0.9      frontend-9b5d57d49-2gmlc
```

The abc-service setup:

```
Name:              abc-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=abc
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.101.14.185
IPs:               10.101.14.185
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        1740/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.4:1740,10.244.0.5:1740,10.244.0.9:1740
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

The image is running 1740 but the node port is exposed to 80.

1st: The nginx will experience intermittent lost of connection to abc-service

2nd: Even though it is a load balancer, it doesn't get redirect to the other pod. It only redirect to one pod. Did I misunderstood its setup?

3rd: I only setup 2 replicas but I got 3 endpoints(10.244.0.4:1740,10.244.0.5:1740,10.244.0.9:1740). What is the last one for?

Comment: The error message connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream means that Nginx tried to pass a request to the upstream server but was unable to establish a connection. This might be caused by either : **Node Server Not Running:** Ensure that the node server is running.If it’s not running, you will have to start your app again. (or)

**Port Misconfiguration:** Ensure that the node server is running on desired port, as Nginx is trying to forward requests to that port.

Comment: The targetPort in the service manifest, and the containerPort in the Deployment manifest need to match the port that the server inside the container is listening on. 

As nginx by default listens on port 80, these should be changed to port 80. Otherwise, the server in the container should be changed to listen on a different port. For nginx this can be done with an nginx.conf file, or by setting an NGINX\_PORT environment variable.